# How to get root of the apport sys.excepthook?

Tags: python, exception, ubuntu

Ubuntu's apport's `sys.excepthook` always crashes for me, probably because I don't have root rights on this machine. It's useless for my own development anyway. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you should have trouble with Ubuntu's apport_excepthook, but you could disable it with:

```
sys.excepthook = sys.__excepthook__
```

Comment: You would need to alter `sys.excepthook` in your Python installation's `sitecustomize.py` file. If you do not have root rights on the machine, I think you could still install a local copy of [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and use it to create an isolated Python environment that you could control. They you could alter that local copy's sitecustomize.py.